# How to resize images on node.js

Tags: node.js, image-compression

So basically my front end is displaying images that are about 3-5mb. I need to find a way to make their size way smaller.

Basically I have the file object on node.js uploading to amazon aws. I just need to compress it before it uploads.

Also whats the best way to resize images on node.js?

Comment: Image files are already compressed (image compression is built into both JPG and PNG formats).  You can make them smaller by making them be a lower resolution (fewer pixels) or by reducing the compression quality (decompress and then recompress at a reduced quality).

Comment: Yea lower resolution

Comment: Lots of images resizers for nodejs here: https://www.google.com/search?q=image+resizer+nodejs

Comment: Put your thoughts on some of them for the answer and I will accept the answer. Also when you answer let me know which one you prefer and also why you picked that specific one.

Comment: I don't have experience with any of them.  I've heard of GraphicsMagick more than the others, but that's all I know.  It is also off-topic here on Stack Overflow to ask for opinions on 3rd party libraries.

Comment: oh okay thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use [Canvas Node js module](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas). This module is up to *3 times faster* than ImageMagic.

Images manipulation comparation - https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

```
author's results:
  canvas.js : 4.001 img/sec;
  gm-imagemagic.js : 1.206 img/sec;
  gm.js : 1.536 img/sec;
  lwip.js : 0.406 img/sec;
```